# after save update attrubutes infinite loop

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

In my loopback application, i am using mongodb as my backend

consider i have 2 collections as A,B. Their relation is `A hasOne B`. So in my `aftersave` hook of model A i have implemented

```
if(isNewInstance) {
   // When creating A i have to compute data 
   // and create a document in B and have to update the _id of B to A    
   // For Updating i am calling:     
   ctx.instances.updateAttributes();// this will once again call this
   //after save hook and with isNewInstance == false, 
   // so it will go in else condition also.
} else {
   // When Updating A i have to compute data and create a document in B
   // and have to update the _id of B to A
}
```

`**Summary**`: SO when creating a new instance of A is triggering twice because of updateAttributes, how can i restrict that like when editing the instance it should call  but not on calling updateAttributes.. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you want to do on `A` and `B` during the `after save` hook ?

Comment: @Overdrivr Thanks.. In afterSave of A i am computing a JSON and creating a document in B(which has _id). I haveto update that _id to a key in A..

Comment: So basically, create an instance of `B` and link it to current instance of `A`. Is this correct ?

Comment: @Overdrivr Exactly..

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isNewInstance) {
   if(ctx.instance.needToUpdate){
     process.nextTick(() => {
      ctx.instance.updateAttributes();
     });
}   
} else {

}
```

Comment: @Subburaj Yes but once